# Run on the specific CPU, not one goroutine?

Tags: windows, go

`golang` just has a method `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)` to set the application run one `goroutine` at the same time,But i want to let the application just run on the specificone cpu?

Comment: start /affinity 1 gobinary.exe

Comment: Setting processor affinity is OS specific, and is best done outside of the process itself. A command line tool like `taskset` on Linux is usually what you use to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To launch you Go binary, say `example.exe` so that it runs only on CPU 0 on Windows, you can use `start` command with "affinity" parameter:

```
start /affinity 1 example.exe
```

I don't know what exactly are you trying to achieve but refer to [this document describing GOMAXPROCS](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1At2Ls5_fhJQ59kDK2DFVhFu3g5mATSXqqV5QrxinasI/edit) - it might be the case that Go runtime will do the same thing more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Under the **gc** compilers (**6g** or **8g**) you must set **GOMAXPROCS** to more than the default value 1 to allow the run-time support to utilize more than one OS thread, that is all goroutines share the same thread unless GOMAXPROCS is set to a value **greater than 1**.

When **GOMAXPROCS** is greater than 1, they run on a thread pool with that many threads. With the **gccgo** compiler GOMAXPROCS is effectively equal to the number of running goroutines. Suppose `n` is the number of processors or cores on the machine. If you set the environment variable `GOMAXPROCS >= n`, or call `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(n)`, then the goroutines are divided (distributed)
among the n processors.

More processors however don’t mean necessarily a linear improvement in performance, mainly because more communication is needed: the message-passing overhead increases. An experiential rule of thumb seems to be that for n cores setting **GOMAXPROCS to n-1** yields the best performance, and the following should also be followed:

`number of goroutines > 1 + GOMAXPROCS > 1`

So if there is only one goroutine executing at a certain point in time, don’t set GOMAXPROCS!

If you wish to lock a goroutine to a particular OS thread you can do this with [runtime.LockOSThread](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread).

> LockOSThread wires the calling goroutine to its current operating
>   system thread. Until the calling goroutine exits or calls
>   UnlockOSThread, it will always execute in that thread, and no other
>   goroutine can.

More about on https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/.

Comment: I don't think it answers OP's question at all. Also, OS thread != CPU core, which I believe is what OP asked for.